# JS works perfect on home machine, not so much on server

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, wordpress, youtube

I'm pulling some videos from youtube to display on a multimedia page on a site. The code has been working fine for a while, but now, mysteriously, it's broken. Testing on my home machine shows everything works fine. Any idea why this might happen? (note: wordpress site, js is external from WP post, code is visible @ [github](https://gist.github.com/709250#file_multimedia.js), no noticeable errors using browser tools or online js lint)

Thanks in advance...

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //some variables
  var videos = [];                      //placeholder for video information returned from youtube
  var video_elm_arr = $('.video');      //array of 'video' elements in DOM      
  //hide videos until ready
  $('.video').addClass('hidden');      
  //pull video data from youtube
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/danwoodson/uploads?alt=json',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
      $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i,item){
        //only take the first 7 videos
        if(i > 6)
          return;              
        //create object to hold the video's info
        videos[i] = {};
        videos[i].title = item.title.$t;
        videos[i].url = item.media$group.media$content[0].url;          //this will need to be cleaned before use
        videos[i].summary = item.content.$t;   
        videos[i].thumbnail = item.media$group.media$thumbnail[3].url;              
        //assign title
        $(video_elm_arr[i]).find('.video_title').append(videos[i].title);            
        //clean url
        var video_url = videos[i].url;
        var index = video_url.indexOf("?");
          if (index > 0)
            video_url = video_url.substring(0, index);
        //and re-assign
        videos[i].url = video_url;                         
        if(i == 0){ //only for featured/main
          //insert flash object in video element
          $(video_elm_arr[i]).find('.video_title').after('<object id="video_0" width="475" height="267.1875">' + 
                                   '<param name="movie" value="' + video_url + '&showinfo=0"></param>' +
                                   '<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>' +
                                   '<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>' +
                                   '<embed src="' + video_url + '&showinfo=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="475" height="267.1875"></embed>' +
                                   '</object>');
          //and include summary
          $(video_elm_arr[i]).find('#featured_summary').html(videos[i].summary);
        }
        else{ //else just use thumbnail and enlarge
          $(video_elm_arr[i]).find('.video_title').after('<img src="' + videos[i].thumbnail +'" alt="video" id="video_' + i + '" />');
          $(video_elm_arr[i]).find('img').animate({height: 84.375, width: 150}, 500);            
        }                       
        //and finally show
        $(video_elm_arr[i]).removeClass('hidden');
      });
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {alert("error with retrieving videos");}
  });      
  //create functionality
  $('.non_featured').bind('click', function(){
    //get clicked video's id
    var clicked_vid_id = $(this).find('img').attr('id');
    //clean
    var index = clicked_vid_id.indexOf("_");
    if (index > 0)
      clicked_vid_id = clicked_vid_id.substring(index+1);        
    //get featured video's id
    var cur_featured_vid_id = $('#featured').find('object').attr('id');
    //clean
    var index = cur_featured_vid_id.indexOf("_");
    if (index > 0)
      cur_featured_vid_id = cur_featured_vid_id.substring(index+1);        
    //create new swf object with clicked video's information
    var new_featured_vid_swf = '<object id="video_' + clicked_vid_id + '" width="475" height="267.1875">' + 
                               '<param name="movie" value="' + videos[clicked_vid_id].url + '?showinfo=0&autoplay=1"></param>' +
                               '<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>' +
                               '<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>' +
                               '<embed src="' + videos[clicked_vid_id].url + '?showinfo=0&autoplay=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="475" height="267.1875"></embed>' +
                               '</object>';        
    //clear out clicked video's image
    $(this).find('img').remove();               
    //clear out featured video's original swf object
    $('#featured').find('object').remove();                
    /*assign newly created swf objects to their appropriate locations*/
    //set clicked
    $(this).find('.video_title').html(videos[cur_featured_vid_id].title);
    $(this).append('<img src="' + videos[cur_featured_vid_id].thumbnail +'" alt="video" id="video_' + cur_featured_vid_id + '" />');
    $(this).find('img').animate({height: 84.375, width: 150}, 500);
    //and set new featured/main
    $('#featured').find('.video_title').html(videos[clicked_vid_id].title);
    $('#featured').find('.video_title').after(new_featured_vid_swf);
    $('#featured').find('#featured_summary').html(videos[clicked_vid_id].summary);        
  });
});
```

Comment: What code are you using to pull in the YouTube videos?

Comment: What does "it's broken" mean?  Help us help you: post minimal relevant code, browser errors, HTTP request logs, etc.  A link to source code doesn't help without more context.

Comment: It'd be very helpful if you check for any errors using Chrome's Developer Tools. Monitor XHR and JavaScript for possible failures.

Comment: What about a link to the WordPress "site"?

Comment: @Joel: I've been using CDTs to check for js errors, but not XHR. Will do.

Comment: @Jonathon: Broken means that all the values I've checked come back correct, but none of the things the js is supposed to put on the page show up. - Best description I have until I can pin-point the error...

When I find the error, if it's still giving me problems, I can post more concise code...

Comment: @danwoods That's a bit more useful.  I would start by using the browser debugger of your choice and throw some breakpoints after your data comes back and step line by line.  Put breakpoints in events and callbacks and make sure they are firing.  Add watches on the jQuery selectors and make sure they are there.  Change the jQuery `html` replacement calls to insert simple test data.  Do you have a link to a live version of the site?

Comment: http://www.headcount.org/headcount-multimedia/   Currently has some alerts set for debugging...

Comment: Jonathon, could you elaborate on adding "watches" to selectors?

Comment: @danwoods most debuggers let you maintain a list of variables or code to "watch" as you step through execution showing changes to variables as they occur.

Comment: Ahh, okay, thought there might have been a way to watch selectors for change. It appears that the jquery can't find my selectors, which is what I kind of assumed was happening. So now the question is why is that happening... (thanks for all your help Jonathon)

Answer (score 0):

From your page, these are the errors that occur.  Internet Explorer, Chrome, and Firefox all have good debuggers/JavaScript consoles available to show this information.

```
'pollsL10n' is undefined  polls-js.js?ver=2.50, line 1 character 62
pollsL10n.show_loading=parseInt(pollsL10n.show_loading)


Object doesn't support this property or method  headcount-multimedia, line 135 character 9
$(".tweet").tweet({


Object doesn't support this property or method  slider.js, line 32 character 4
jQuery("#main-photo-slider").codaSlider();

Object doesn't support this property or method  main.js, line 31 character 1
jQuery.cookie('widget widget_text');
```

Comment: Right. Those errors were present before the page stopped working, and nothing I've worked on (I'm an intern). I still feel like it's a problem with jQuery finding the selectors (which is so weird...)

Comment: Figured out why jQuery wasn't finding the selectors. Now it finds them, but still does't add the content it's supposed to

Comment: Errors like those above can interfere with anything that comes after that point in those scripts.  The script stops executing when they occur...may or may not have something to do with the issues you're seeing.